# Why is the function only returning the multiplied value?

Tags: c, function, return-value, declaration, definition

Why this code is returning 500 and some garbage value? Why isnt the divide function working?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int divmul(int v1, int v2)
{
    int div,mul;
    div =v1/v2;
    mul=v1*v2;
    return div,mul;
}
main()
{
    int val1=50, val2=10;
    printf("%d %d\n", divmul(val1,val2));
}
```

Comment: _function divmul_ will only return a single `int`value and the garbadge value is coming out due to second `%d`.

Comment: Better question: Why this even compile? How can be this valid? `return div,mul;` ..and this do compile. Weird.

Comment: Function return a single value in your case , please check the link   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement

Comment: @Eraklon It's not weird at all.  `div,mul` is just [the C comma operator](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17).

Comment: I guess you came from python world!!

Comment: I would consider a function like that to do just one operation at all, in particular: `int div(int v1, int v2)` and `int mul(int v1, int v2)`
For changing more variables at once by the function check out [call by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm)

Comment: @Andrew Henle I started programing in C 6 years ago and never seen code like this. Good to know this can happen, but saying its not weird. I wonder how often people encounter this kind of code. 

Does this returning syntax can be useful at any scenario by the way?

Comment: @Eraklon there is only one syntax. `return` keyword is followed by 1 expression or not. And whatever matches the syntax for "expressions" can be used for `return` as well. Syntax definition does not care about "usefullness".

Comment: The compiler should complain about missing parameter for format string. If not, the warning level should be increased.

Comment: regarding: `main()`   This will cause the compiler to output a warning message about the returned type not being `int`.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnngs.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding this syntax error: `return div,mul;`  This results in the compiler outputting the message: *untitled2.c:8:15: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]*

Comment: A called function can only return a single value (which can be a struct)  so this statement: `printf("%d %d\n", divmul(val1,val2));`  does not compiler as it has one too many output format conversion specifiers.

Answer (score 7):

A function can return only one object using the return statement.

In this return statement

```
return div,mul;
```

there is used an expression with the comma operator. Its value is the value of the right operand. So in fact as the expression `div` has no side effect then the return statement is equivalent to

```
return mul;
```

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
>   of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
>   has its type and value. And the compiler will issue an error for the
>   printf call because there are no enough arguments.

Either declare as the return type a structure as for example

```
struct Result
{
    int div;
    int mul;
};

struct Result divmul( int v1, int v2 )
{
    struct Result result = { v1 / v2, v1 * v2 };

    return result;
}
```

and then in main

```
int main( void )
{
    int val1 = 50, val2 = 10;

    struct Result result = divmul( val1, val2 );

    printf( "%d %d\n", result.div, result.mul );
}
```

Or return the result from the function parameters (the so-called output parameters)

```
void divmul( int *v1, int *v2 )
{
    int div = *v1 / *v2;
    int mul = *v1 * *v2;

    *v1 = div;
    *v2 = mul;
}
```

And in main

```
int main( void )
{
    int val1 = 50, val2 = 10;

    divmul( &val1, &val2 );

    printf( "%d %d\n", val1, val2 );
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```